# Pull up login times in sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm having a little trouble getting info from my database. I have a table containing two columns, one the player name, and the other the login time. I want to get a list of players and the number of times they logged in during a time period. However, users can login multiple times a day, but I want all logins within the same day to be counted as once.

To put this into context, I want a list of player name and the number of days in which the users have logged in during 2013-11-18 to 2013-11-24.

Is there a query that can return this result in one go?

I have tried using GROUP BY player_name but that just gives the number of times the player have logged in in total (large numbers because each player may login multiple times a day).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT player_name, COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(login_time))
FROM login_table
GROUP BY player_name;
```

Nail it, let me know if it doesnt work :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but this should do the job:

```
Select  player_name, count(logged_in)
From    (Select player_name, Date(login_date) As logged_in From ... Group By player_name, Date(login_date)) as tmp
Group   By player_name
```

EDIT: Derived table must have an alias

Comment: I tried this but it tells me invalid syntax near GROUP (the second group by clause). I'm not sure why...

Comment: Try to add alias to derived table